# Trigger to include the TODAY update

Tags: trigger

I have the following trigger that is working fine. I just want to include this date field Last_Showing_Date__c to be updated with the TODAY. The field is on the contact object.

Can you please help me on how to do that.

```
trigger showingWorkflowTrigger on Event (after insert, after update) {
    List<Event> events = Trigger.new;
    Map<Id, Event> oldEvents = null;
    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        oldEvents = Trigger.oldMap;
    }
    for (Event event : events) {
        RecordType rt = [Select Name FROM RecordType where Id = :event.RecordTypeId];
        if (rt.Name == 'Showing' && event.WhoId != null) {
            //cambiar el stage del contacto a 'Showing'
            Contact co = [Select Stage_fm__c from Contact where Id = :event.WhoId];
            if (co == null) {
                continue; //No es un contacto
            }

            if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
                //también puede ser que sea un update y anteriormente no tuviese contacto
                Event oldEvent = oldEvents.get(event.Id);
                if (oldEvent.WhoId != null) {
                    Contact oldCo = [Select Stage_fm__c from Contact where Id = :oldEvent.WhoId];
                    if (oldCo != null && oldCo.Id == co.Id) {
                        continue; //Es el mismo contacto
                    }
                }
            }
            if (co.Stage_fm__c != 'Offer' &&  co.Stage_fm__c != 'Showing') { //Si ya está en offer, lo djamos igual
                co.Stage_fm__c = 'Showing';
                update co;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: uyou can update today date with date class like Last_Showing_Date__c = Date.Today()

Comment: Please explain a bit briefly where you want to update the contact with any criteria.

Comment: I don't know how to include the line of code in to the trigger. So basically what this trigger is doing is when you have a new event Showing is changing the stage of the contact to Showing. What I want to achieve is to track the showing date

Comment: While I don't have the answer, I would highly suggest moving this code into a class and refactoring the update out of your loop. You're setting yourself up for major issues in the future if you don't.

Answer (score 2):

You can use workflow rule here.

**Rule**:
AND( PRIORVALUE(Stage_fm__c) = 'Showing' , Stage_fm__c != 'Showing')

**Field Update on Last_Showing_Date__c**: Today()

Comment: I know I can use a workflow rule, it was just to keep everything in one place and since I have the trigger I wanted to do it there

Comment: Clicks not code.